# Ubuntu 12.04 boots into wrong virtual console

Tags: ubuntu

If I turn on my PC with Ubuntu 12.04, then it displays information from seventh virtual console. It is also the one where X server should be started. Last messages I see in seventh virtual console are:

```
* Setting sysfs variables...                       [ OK ]
* Starting Mail Transport Agent (MTA) sendmail     [ OK ]
* Starting web server apache2                      [ OK ]
```

Even if I wait for more than five minutes, nothing happens. However, if I go to eighth virtual console(Ctrl+Alt+8), then I see the GDM login-screen. What might cause such behavior? How to change the default virtual console from seventh to eight?

Comment: Ubuntu boots into correct virtual console - it's X server starting on the wrong console. Also, do you use drivers from nvidia?

Comment: No, I use radeon.ko driver which came with the kernel 3.2.0-23. How do you change the virtual console where X server starts?

Comment: X server starts on first free vt, it seems that there's a problem with vt7 that it is allocated by something else. I recommend trying different driver (e.g. fglrx) or disabling gdm and manually debugging start of X server (you can start x on specific vt by `startx -- vt7`)